# JS onload event not working

Tags: javascript

i want to language control in html page,

```
<div id="tr" class="dilK" style="padding:10px;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">

</div>

<div id="en" onload="hide()" class="dilK" style="padding:10px;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">

</div>
```

and my script

```
<script>
 var link = window.location.href;
 var deger = link.substring(link.indexOf('?')+4);
 if (deger==tr) {
     //document.getElementById("en").style = "display:none";
     $(document).ready ( function(){
         function hide() {
             alert("içerde");
             document.getElementById("en").style.display = "none";
         }
     })
 }
 alert(deger);
```

when i run the code, var deger==tr and alert(deger) running but function hide don't work.

Comment: Do not use `$(document).ready` inside the native js function.

Comment: What is `<div onload="` meant to do? It's not an image. Do you want to run `hide` once the document loads?

Comment: @CertainPerformance if the querystring value= tr , i will hide div id=en and querystring =en, hide div id=tr.

Comment: But when? On document load, or what? Divs don't have `onload` attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot use onload on div.

use [onload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) on body

try below snipet

```js
var link = window.location.href;
var deger = link.substring(link.indexOf('?')+4);
if (deger==tr) {
  //document.getElementById("en").style = "display:none";
}
function hide() {
  alert("içerde");
  document.getElementById("en").style.display = "none";
}
alert(deger);
```

```html
<body onload="hide()" >
<div id="tr" class="dilK" style="padding:10px;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">

</div>

<div id="en" class="dilK" style="padding:10px;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather having the event on the div, use the below code.

```
<div id="en" class="dilK" style="padding:10px;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#en').hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry in "document.ready" event, we can hide the element directly



$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#en').hide();
});